# How to use OR in if statement in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Did I use "OR" correctly in my below code. Could someone help me please?

```
If Cells(i, 3).Value = "BRI TELECOM" Or "CHR INTERNATIO" Or "AG" Or "IMAG COMMUNICATIONS CORP" Then
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you didn't:

```
If Cells(i, 3).Value = "BRITISH TELECOM" Or _
   Cells(i, 3).Value = "CHRISTIES INTERNATIO" Or _
   Cells(i, 3).Value = "DTAG" Or _
   Cells(i, 3).Value = "IMAGINE COMMUNICATIONS CORP" Then
```

---

An alternative would be to use a `Select Case` statement.  These are especially useful if you have many conditions to test:

```
Select Case Cells(i, 3).Value
    Case "BRITISH TELECOM", _
         "CHRISTIES INTERNATIO", _
         "DTAG", _
         "IMAGINE COMMUNICATIONS CORP"

        'Do something

    Case "Some other string", _
         "and another string"

        'Do something else

    Case Else

        'Do something if none of the other statements evaluated to True

End Select
```

That `Select Case` statement would be equivalent to the following `If` statement:

```
If Cells(i, 3).Value = "BRITISH TELECOM" Or _
   Cells(i, 3).Value = "CHRISTIES INTERNATIO" Or _
   Cells(i, 3).Value = "DTAG" Or _
   Cells(i, 3).Value = "IMAGINE COMMUNICATIONS CORP" Then

        'Do something

ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value = "Some other string" Or _
       Cells(i, 3).Value = "and another string" Then

        'Do something else

Else

        'Do something if none of the other statements evaluated to True

End If
```

---

**Unrelated to the actual question, but in response to a further question in comments:**

If you have error values in your data, they will not be able to be compared to Strings, so you will need to test for errors first.

For example:

```
If IsError(Cells(i, 3).Value) Then

    'Do whatever you want to do with error values such as #N/A

ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value = "BRITISH TELECOM" Or _
   Cells(i, 3).Value = "CHRISTIES INTERNATIO" Or _
   Cells(i, 3).Value = "DTAG" Or _
   Cells(i, 3).Value = "IMAGINE COMMUNICATIONS CORP" Then

    '...
```

or

```
If IsError(Cells(i, 3).Value) Then

    'Do whatever you want to do with error values such as #N/A

Else    

    Select Case Cells(i, 3).Value
        Case "BRITISH TELECOM", _
             "CHRISTIES INTERNATIO", _
             "DTAG", _
             "IMAGINE COMMUNICATIONS CORP"

            'Do something

        Case "Some other string", _
             "and another string"

            'Do something else

        Case Else

            'Do something if none of the other statements evaluated to True

    End Select

End If
```

Comment: Now I'm thinking if I should post my answer with Select Case??? No, I'll let you close it up ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado Happy?

Comment: Thanks, I am getting type mismatch error (Run time error '13':)

Comment: @YowE3K  very , now I can have my nap ;)

Comment: Is the value in the cell at the intersection of column C and row `i` a string value?  Or is it possibly an error value such as `#N/A` or `#DIV/0!`?

Comment: @ShaiRado HEY!  You are meant to be awake now so that I can go to sleep!  (It's past my bed-time - good thing tomorrow is Saturday so I can sleep in.)

Comment: @YowE3K, I have both strings as well as #N/A

Comment: @Jagadeesh Error values (such as `#N/A`) can't be compared to a string - you will need to wrap your code in an `If IsError(x) Then` style statement.  I'll edit the answer to also handle that.  (Although it has nothing to do with your question, so should really be a new question.)

Comment: @YowE3K you are brilliant!, works flawlessly thank you so much!